# Where does the Calypso's Compass lead me to?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've gotten it only a couple times, but each time I try to follow it, I die in the harder areas. What does it evetually lead me to, and would I be able to find whatever it is without having the compass, just by searching every room of the castle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compass leads you to a secret room that contains 2 chests. The chests usually contain blueprints or stat upgrades.

From my experience they were good blueprints (armor I was not finding in the area normally).

You will not be able to locate the room without the compass.

edit: [user2339067](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/132826/30210) says he was able to get to the room without the compass, so it might be possible. I have yet to find/confirm this information independently with any other online resources.

Comment: What about with the Spelunker(ette)'s headlamp? Will the two chests be shown on the map then?

Comment: I have not tested it, but I do not think they are not on the actual map. the only indicator that you found the secret room is the 'up arrow' bubble shows up when you stand still in front of the door. The door itself does not look like a door either. I did't check the map while in the room, but mechanically it is likely the same as traveling to a boss room.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information:

You can find the room without the compass, there will however not be ANY indications for it except for seeing an up arrow in a random location in the room.

Source: I found it randomly when I did not have the compass